# Stack approach to find the soonest warmer daily temperature

Tags: python

I am working an [Daily Temperatures - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/)

> 739. Daily Temperature
>
> Given a list of daily temperatures `T`, return a list such that, for each day in the input, tells you how many days you would have to wait until a warmer temperature. If there is no future day for which this is possible, put `0` instead.
>
> For example, given the list of temperatures `T = [73, 74, 75, 71, 69, 72, 76, 73]`, your output should be `[1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]`.
>
> **Note:** The length of `temperatures` will be in the range `[1, 30000]`. Each temperature will be an integer in the range

Analyze the question

> ```
>     Given:nums, list a daily temperature, len(nums) < 30000, in range[30, 100]
>     Find:How many days to wait until a warmmer temperature, soonest 
>     Requirements: if empty return 0,
> ```

A brute force solution with two pointers (O(n**2))

```py
class Solution1:
    def dailyTperatures(self, nums: 'List[int]') -> 'List[int]':
        res = [0] * len(nums)
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i, len(nums)):
                if nums[j] > nums[i]:
                    res[i] = j - i 
                    break #guarentee the soonest 
        return res
```

Re-check the question and find don't make use of the Given condition `range[30,100]`

The official answer take advantage of the condition,

The plan is to employ a `next array` to store (remember) index with higher temperature.

```py
class Solution2:
    def dailyTemperatures(self, nums):
        """
        Runtime: 976 ms, faster than 8.40%
        Memory Usage: 16.6 MB, less than 11.02% 
        """
        nxt = [float('inf')] * 102
        res = [0] * len(nums)
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
            #Use 102 so min(nxt[t]) has a default value
            j= min(nxt[t] for t in range(nums[i]+1, 102))
            if j< float('inf'):
                res[i] = j- i
            nxt[nums[i]] = i
        return res
```

Until now, there is still one condition left `len(nums) < 30000`.   I checked all other solutions but did not find this condition is any of usage among them.

The official `stack` solution starts with a good question

> Consider trying to find the next warmer occurrence at `T[i]`. What information (about `T[j]` for `j > i`) must we remember?

the idea is to remember the indexes with higher temperature using a stack.

```py
class Solution3:
    def dailyTemperatures(self, nums):
        res = [0] * len(nums)
        stack = [] #indexes from hottest to coldest
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
            while stack and nums[i] >= nums[stack[-1]]:
                stack.pop() #remove lower and not soonest 
            if stack:
                res[i] = stack[-1] - i
            stack.append(i)
        return res
```

A more elegant solution  with the same idea.

```py
class Solution4:
    def dailyTemperatures(self, nums: 'List[int]') -> 'List[int]':
        """
        Runtime: 300 ms, faster than 74.12%
        Memory Usage: 16.6 MB, less than 9.45%
        """
        res = [0] * len(nums)
        stack = []
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            while stack and nums[i] > nums[stack[-1]]: #find the higher
                cur = stack.pop()
                res[cur] = i - cur
            stack.append(i)                    
        return res
```

Conclude:

Among all the above solutions, condition `len(nums) < 30000` was not utilized.

What does this condition mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `len(nums) < 30000` is used to tell you the scale of data. you may use different design policy when face different data scale.

For example, `if len(nums) < 30`, brute force may be the best solution, no extra space and fast enough.

You will find many problems in Leetcode also give you this information. And you will not use it in code, but in idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a list comprehension using enumerate() and the index() function:

```
[ [t<n for n in T[i:]+[t+1]].index(True)%(len(T)-i) for i,t in enumerate(T)]

# [1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

If performance is a concern, a procedural approach will run much faster:

```
def dailyTemps(T):
    result = [0]*len(T)
    seeking = []
    prevTemp = 0
    for i,(t0,t1) in enumerate(zip(T,T[1:])):        
        while seeking and prevTemp < t0:
            ip = seeking.pop(-1)
            result[ip] = i - ip
            if seeking: prevTemp = T[seeking[-1]]
        if t0 >= t1:
            seeking.append(i)
            prevTemp = t0
        else:
            result[i] = 1
    return result
```